# Panyushev's conjectured duality for root poset antichains

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, posets, root-systems

In his 2004 paper "ad-nilpotent ideals of a Borel subalgebra: generators and duality" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869303006380), Panyushev conjectured (Conjecture 6.1) the existence of a certain natural involution on the set of antichains of the root poset $\Phi^+$ of an irreducible crystallographic root system $\Phi$. The main property desired is that an antichain of cardinality $k$ is sent to an antichain of cardinality $n-k$, where $n$ is the number of simple roots of $\Phi$. In that paper he constructs the desired involution for Type A, and Type B/C.

**Question**: Have there been any updates/progress on this conjecture?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83594/motivation-behind-panyushevs-constant-averages-along-orbits-conjecture for an MO question regarding further threads of Panyushev's investigation of the root poset

Comment: There are some further developments in https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02329 (namely, Type D is addressed as well) but still not a wholly satisfactory resolution.